# SQL 2008 SSIS Data Flow SQL Command using Subquery on Max field returns part of whole field

Tags: ssis, subquery, max, clob, truncation

I am converting an Oracle CLOB defined field to SQL Max defined field. My input Oracle CLOB defined field contains datat larger than 8000 bytes for example SSIS brings in a field with 85,000 characters but only converts 100 bytes. In the SSIS Data Flow Advanced Editor the OLE DB Source Output External Columns shows Data Type as "text stream[DT_TEXT] and Length of 0 (zero). The SQL Command field in the Advanced Editor has been tested with a single query Select * from table_name of which all 85,000 characters are converted. However I use the subquery that I need, only 100 characters are converted from the field that contains any data larger than 100 characters.  I can provide additional info but my main stab at this is to find out if anyone has experience using multi-query SQL in the SQL Command window of SSIS data flow and has experienced the data loss that I am experiencing?  thanks

New info: 
if I run this query my LXDESC field is truncated to 100 bytes.

```
select * from (
SELECT  LXOID,  LXKIND, LXDESC
 FROM v6dp1.LXDESC_67206C5B
WHERE lxoid = ' -2122313890')
```

if I remove the top query and only run the below query, I get all the data

```
SELECT  LXOID,  LXKIND, LXDESC
 FROM v6dp1.LXDESC_67206C5B
WHERE lxoid = ' -2122313890'
```

Sounds very similar to existing question: OLE DB SOURCE truncation

Comment: The question is a little confusing. You are attempting to move data from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS. Things look good. Then (?) you use the same query but with a subquery against it and then I get lost.

Comment: If I run a simple SELECT query, my MAX defined field (LXDESC) contains all my data (85000 characters).  If I make a simple subquery using the same SELECT query, I only get back 100 characters in the same field.  This simple test shows there is a problem pull large fields defined as MAX thru SSIS.  This example queries an Oracle (CLOB) field and attempts to write a SQL Server MAX field.

Comment: It appears that your source provider is getting confused to hell over the derived/sub table approach. I don't have Oracle to beat against so I can only offer general SSIS approaches. Add two source components, whether it's OLE or ADO, shouldn't matter. The query for one is the first query, second gets the second query. Wire up a Derived Column to each of them. Double click on the connector between the two and in the Metadata section, do they both show DT_TEXT as your type (length will be irrelevant)? Generally speaking, if SSIS detects truncation, it blows up instead of silently accepting it.